# AutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBean(bean) never invoke InitlizingBean.afterPropertiesSet()?

Tags: java, spring

I need to do some initialization work after bean properties set,

```
ApplicationContext context = new ...;
AutowireCapableBeanFactory factory = context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();

// autowireBean only populate the fields, but never invoke afterPropertiesSet().
factory.autowireBean(bean);

// Should I set it manually?
// if (bean instanceof InitializingBean) {
//    ((InitializingBean) bean).afterPropertiesSet();
// }
// if (bean instanceof ApplicationContextAware) {
//    ((ApplicationContextAware) bean).setApplicationContext(context); 
// }
// if ...
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
factory.autowireBean(bean);
bean = (YourBean) factory.initializeBean(bean, "anyName");
```

It works with `@PostConstruct` (which I would recommend), so it should execute `afterPropertiesSet()` as well. `anyName` is the bean name, probably used when [`BeanNameAware`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanNameAware.html) interface is involved.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The documentation says the method autowires the bean, and nothing else.

There are other methods in the factory that take care of initialization, but they require a bean definition.